# Best exception to use in Java for bad xml input

Tags: java, android, xml, exception, dom

I'm writing a class in java (for android) that accepts an [org.w3c.dom.Element](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) as input and provides some business logic functions around it.  In one of those functions, I call [getElementsByTagName](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName(java.lang.String)) and expect only 1 element in the returned [NodeList](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html).  If there's more than 1 element, it means the [Element](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Element.html) I got is jacked up somehow and I need to throw an exception. Is there an exception already included in JDK7 which is made to accurately represent this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the method throw an `IllegalArgumentException`:

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.

Or you could write your own `Exception` class which may be a better solution if you're following this exception-driven approach.

Note however that using exceptions for flow control can cause lower performance.

Comment: Usually we try to avoid using runtime exceptions for cases like this, except that I think it would be stupid to require every caller to explicitly handle the case where they pass bad input.  They should be doing their own data validation, and if we somehow ever get bad input, they're doing something really wrong and we should just kill everything, which a runtime exception is perfect for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's best to define your own Exception, as none of the Java defined exceptions quite fit the case you're experiencing, and it doesn't seem that people outside your organization need to understand the thrown exception.